# Is there a way to remove bower dependencies using ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I installed a bower dependency using `ember-cli` as follows:

```
ember install:bower utf8
```

Is there an equivalent way to uninstall the same dependency?

So far I have resorted to:

```
bower uninstall utf8
```

And then manually edited the bower.json file. Is there a more correct way to do this? Or are there any drawbacks of doing it my way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You just have to use `--save` or `--save-dev`:

```
$ bower uninstall utf8 --save
```

When you use `--save`, then it's uninstalled and removed from `dependencies` section, and `--save-dev` removes it from `devDependencies`.

You can use the same flags with `bower install` or even `npm install`/`npm uninstall`.

EDIT:

Here's a reasoning why they don't want to make an alias for `bower uninstall`: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3163